# service-worker status failed but status code return 200

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker

I want to use service worker to proxy request and storage the response to cacheStorage, but there is a request return fail but status code return 200!

Failed request
[image: Failed request]

Fine request- returns HTTP 200
[image]

I want to know why browser return different status for this request.